# Why is there a difference in memory usage depending on the location of the list function?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

This is my submission code for leetcode algorithm problem(https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/)

I just use `itertools.combinations()` to solve this problem.

The first case memory usage is 14.4 MB

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        for x in range(len(nums) + 1):
            result.extend(itertools.combinations(nums, x))
        result = [list(x) for x in result] # located in list comprehension 
            
        return result
```

The second case memory usage is 14.6 MB

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        result = []
        for x in range(len(nums) + 1):
            result.extend(list(itertools.combinations(nums, x))) # located in extend function
            
        return result
```

The only difference is location of `list()`.

Why is there a difference in memory usage?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried simply printing the results of your 2 options? You'll see first one contains lists which are mutable objects, hence likely come with extra memory allocation, while the second contain immutable tuples which have likely better optimized memory footprint...